# PHPStorm 7 Live Edit + Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, phpstorm

Скачал новую версию PHPStorm (131.374), перестал работать live edit в Chrome

1. Запускал в Ubuntu и в Windows
2. переустанавливал приложение в Chrome
3. с Версией PHPStorm 6.0.3 все работает на обеих осях
4. в Chrome по адресу 127.0.0.1:63342 пишет "404 Not Found --- PhpStorm 7.0"

Есть решение у кого ни будь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раньше был автоматический дебагинг а теперь нужно на файле кликнуть правой мышью и нажать Debag filename.html